# R import large csv with commas with double backslash in readr or data.table

Tags: r, regex, csv, data.table, readr

I'm having trouble importing a large csv file (17m rows) into R.  I've tried using both `readr::read_csv` and `data.table::fread` but both are creating extra columns.  This is because one of the columns has some text that includes commas.  When I read the file with `readLines`, I can see that the commas within the text are preceded by a double-backslash so they should be ignored, however I can't get either package to ignore them... Any suggestion?
An example would be:

```
id,title
 1,great expectations
 2,great expectations\\, the sequel
```

Comment: Please include a few rows of the data

Comment: What software created this invalid file?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a beautiful solution but you could take advantage of `data.table::fread`'s ability to pass shell commands to `input` and preprocess your csv file to swap the first comma in each line with another delimiter:

```
library(data.table)
fread(input = "sed 's/,/_/' foo.csv", sep = "_")

##    id                              title
## 1:  1                 great expectations
## 2:  2 great expectations\\\\, the sequel
```

In this example I'm using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to swap the first comma in each line with an underscore before it's passed to `fread()`.

This is assuming you're using a unix-like environment in which `sed` is available.

Comment: thanks for that.  It didn't work on my file though and i'm not sure why... would you be able to explain what sed 's/,/_/' do?

Comment: Updated the answer with a clarification and qualification. It would be easier to help if you provided a larger subset of the data and described what happened when you tried running the code.

Comment: I see... unfortunately replacing just the first comma wouldn't work for my file (i'm sorry, i don't know how i could supply a subset of my data....) is there a solution with the sed command that would replace all instances of \\, with an underscore?

Comment: Sure. You *could* modify the statement to `sed 's/,/_/g'`; that trailing `g` triggers a global replacement but that shouldn't be necessary if your table truly includes only 2 columns. If it's more complex than that you'll need to upload a subset of it to something like pastebin or provide a minimal reproducible example.